# Azure ADLS Gen2 file created by Azure Databricks doesn't inherit ACL

Tags: acl, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a databricks notebook that is writing a dataframe to a file in ADLS Gen2 storage.

It creates a temp folder, outputs the file and then copies that file to a permanent folder.  For some reason the file doesn't inherit the ACL correctly.  The folder it creates has the correct ACL.

The code for the notebook:

```py
#Get data into dataframe
df_export = spark.sql(SQL)

# OUTPUT file to temp directory coalesce(1) creates a single output data file
(df_export.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet")
.mode("overwrite")
.save(TempFolder))

#get the parquet file name.  It's always the last in the folder as the other files are created starting with _
file = dbutils.fs.ls(TempFolder)[-1][0]

#create permanent copy
dbutils.fs.cp(file,FullPath)
```

The temp folder that is created shows the following for the relevant account.
[image: Folder Permissions]

Where the file shows the following.

[image: File Permission]

There is also a mask.  I'm not really familiar with masks so not sure how this differs.

The Mask permission on the folder shows

[image: Mask Folder Permissions]

On the file it shows as

[image: Mask File Permission]

Does anyone have any idea why this wouldn't be inheriting the ACL from the parent folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a response from Microsoft support which has resolved this issue for me.

Cause:  Databricks stored files have Service principal as the owner of the files with permission -rw-r--r--, consequently forcing the effective permission of rest of batch users in ADLS from rwx (directory permission) to r-- which in turn causes jobs to fail

Resolution: To resolve this, we need to change the default mask (022) to custom mask (000) on Databricks end. You can set the following in Spark Configuration settings under your cluster configuration: spark.hadoop.fs.permissions.umask-mode 000

Answer (score 2):

Wow, thats great! I was looking for a solution. Passthrough Authentication might be a proper solution now.

I had the feeling it was part of this acient hadoop bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962 (solved in hadoop-3, now part of spark 3+).

Spark tries to set the ACL's after moving the files, but fails. First the files are created somewhere else in a tmp dir. The tmp-dir rights are inherated by default adls-behaviour.